# React - API populated state is undefined

Tags: reactjs

In an App, I have added an API request in the ComponentDidMount method. I used an `axios.get(...).then(callback)`
approach, with the callback being a setState of the data.

Then, the data which will be stored in the state, should be passed along in some child components. 
The issue I'm seeing is that the child components are attempted to be rendered when the data is not yet there, leading to e.g. `this.state.somedata is undefined`

I can fix this by e.g. checking what it's value is before the render, but if the data is used in several Components, this becomes messy.

What would be the best approach to circumvent this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: are you rendering child components using .map method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reminds me of the ["always be ready to render"](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/#principle-2-always-be-ready-to-render) principle described by Dan Abramov.

In your scenario the component that makes the API call has the following states:

- Loading: request is in-flight
- Success: API returned the data
- Error: API request failed

These states can either be handled in the top-level component (the one making the API call), or be passed on to its children.

In the first approach the top-level component would only render its children when the data they depend on exists. Conceptually its render method would look like this:

```js
render() {
  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  if (data) {
    // return child components 
  }

  if (error) {
    return <p>{error.message}</p>
  }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that it simplifies the implementation of the child components, since they are only rendered when data is present. Additionally the states associated with the API call are handled once, co-located with the component making the request.

The second approach as you allude to would require each child component to check whether data is present before using it. This would offer more control over the UI in the loading/success/error states, and allow any children that don't use data to be rendered immediately.

Answer (score 0):

That is just the nature of asynchronous code, this isn't "strange" behavior that should be circumvented. The loading/pending state of the requests should be handled accordingly with renders that display placeholders, loading bars, etc.

Remember that `setState` is asynchronous as well so the state update is not always guaranteed to be complete when you expect it.